# Split function splitting words with punctuations. Want to prevent. After splitting how to Alphabetize?

Tags: python, text, split

I have two issues. Here goes the code:

```
Read =open("C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop/test1.txt",'r')
text =Read.read()
words =text.split()
print(words)
print(words.sort())

##counts=dict()
##for word in words:
##    counts[word] = counts.get(word,0)+1
##
##
##print counts
```

And the text that I am trying to read:

**test1.txt**

Hello Hello Hello.

How is everything. What is going on?
Where are you? Hello!!

Hope to see you soon.

When are you coming by?

What should I make for dinner?

The end!

**End of text from txt file**

My two questions are the following:

1. I'm trying to implement a count-each-word code where I count the number of times each word appears in a document. 
   However when I split the words using the above code, the word "Hello" will appear as "Hello!," or even "Hello." separately.  How can I avoid this?
2. Next, I tried to sort the elements of the list, alphabetically, but all I get in return after running the `sort()` method is `none` which is really confusing me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should take a look at [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work for what you described:

```
import re

with open("C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop/test1.txt", 'r') as file:
    file = file.read()

words_list = re.findall(r"[\w]+", file)
words_list = sorted(words_list, key=str.lower)

patterns = ["Hello"]
counter = 0


for word in words_list:
    for pattern in patterns:
        if word == pattern:
            counter+=1

print("The word Hello occurred {0} times".format(counter)) # prints the number of times 'Hello' was found
print(words_list) # prints your list alphabetically
```

There are a few things you should note however:

- I used the `re` module instead of sort. This is because using the [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) engine in the re module would be much less complex than trying to split the strings using the `split()` function.
- I renamed some of your variables to follow the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guide and naming convention for Python. Feel free to rename to your liking.
- the reason that **`sort()`** returned a list, is because the `sort()` attribute of a list, does not return a new list, but changes the old one. That is, the `sort()` attribute of a list sorts in place. The `sort()` you were using returns the data type `None`. You need to use the builtin Python function  **`sorted()`** instead. The `sorted()` function returns the data type `list`.

Comment: Would not be better to open the file with the `with` statement, just to be sure that the memory is released after reading it?

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to play around with the code and re module　and see if I have any further questions.

As for "the reason sort() returned a list, is because the sort() attribute of a list, does not return a new list, but changes the old one. That is, the sort() attribute of a list sorts in place. You need to use the builtin Python function sorted() instead"

I'm a little confused with this comment. 
The SORT function didn't return a list, it returned a NONE (unless this is a list)

Comment: @moondra I'll see if I can clarify in my answer.